"WARNING: Incorrect integer value" notices in mysql_error log
I've been seeing a ton of these warnings in mysql_error log, a literal ton of them, from various websites on the server and various databases, mostly Wordpress, and they all look like this:
WARNING 1366: Incorrect integer value: '' for column...
WARNING 1292: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''...
WARNING 1364: Field 'attackLogTime' doesn't have a default value :...
WARNING 1292: Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '' ...

And they are referring to well know Wordpress plugins like Wordfence and such, which I would assume would have their coding down pat and correct to avoid any obvious mysql errors. But since these are simply warnings, how do I turn these off, or ignore these "incorrect integer / decimal value / no default value" issues so that I can actually have a usable mysql_error log and find more important issues in there that need my attention?
I'm on MariaDB 11.4, and here is my.cnf configuration as well:
[mysqld]
default_storage_engine              = InnoDB
datadir                             = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                              = /var/lib/mysql/tmp
log-error                           = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_errors.log
slow_query_log_file                 = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_slow_queries.log
sql-mode                            = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
pid-file                            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
socket                              = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links                      = 0
max_allowed_packet                  = 256M
max_connections                     = 500
max_connect_errors                  = 20
open_files_limit                    = 50000
wait_timeout                        = 90
connect_timeout                     = 90
interactive_timeout                 = 90
tmp_table_size                      = 128M
max_heap_table_size                 = 128M
max_statement_time                  = 180
innodb_strict_mode                  = 0
log_warnings                        = 0
back_log                            = 512

slow_query_log                      = 1
long_query_time                     = 5

table_open_cache                    = 15K
table_definition_cache              = 15K
table_open_cache_instances          = 16
query_cache_type                    = 0
query_cache_size                    = 0
query_cache_limit                   = 1M #8M
thread_cache_size                   = 100 #256
thread_handling                     = pool-of-threads
key_buffer_size                     = 64M #256M
join_buffer_size                    = 20M

# [InnoDB]
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 20G
innodb_log_file_size                = 5G
innodb_file_per_table               = 1

# [Misc]
concurrent_insert                   = 1
local_infile                        = 1
group_concat_max_len                = 102400
innodb_file_per_table               = 1

innodb_monitor_enable               = all
log_slow_verbosity                  = query_plan,explain
performance_schema                  = ON

# [Custom]
collation-server                    = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect                        = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server                = utf8mb4
table_open_cache_instances          = 16

sql-error-log-size-limit            = 50M
sql-error-log-rotate                = 1
sql-error-log-filename              = mysql_query_errors.log

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet                  = 256M

[myisamchk]
bind-address                        = 127.0.0.1
max_allowed_packet                  = 50M #256M

And no, I can't just go into every website hosted on the server and every plugin and "fix" their code or mysql structure... it would take forever, as it spans dozens of sites and plugins, and even then it would get overwritten with their next update which I have zero control over. That's not a feasible solution, so I am asking for suggestions on how else I can turn these warnings off?
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

It's a problem in the PHP code. They are writing empty values into the database. Report it as a bug.

Yeah, report it on dozens of plugins? And it's not just that, it's some sort of casting or pulling the data out of tables expecting it to be DECIMAL or INTEGER... across tons of plugins and tables. There's gotta be a way to just turn these WARNINGS off on MariaDB, as they're not really errors that break the functionality.

And what are you missing in the documentation?

What am I missing? The part where I set log_warnings = 0 and it's still producing these warnings constantly, that's what.

Which plugin has attackLogTime?  Maybe we can discuss it.

I don't know, I think it was Wordfence... how is that relevant to the question here?

Turning warnings off is never a solution. You see the warning, find the code that issues the warning, you fix the code, this is how it's done. In the present form the question reads: "I don't want to do the job right (it requires effort), so how can I just hide the trash under the carpet", which is unreasonable way to do things, it's off topic here.

I agree, but with all due respect, you missed the whole point of it - it's NOT my code. It's code across dozens of free and paid Wordpress plugins that's triggering these warnings. I can't just go "fix it", as you suggest, as that's not feasible (as my fixes and changes, if I was to do so, would get wiped out with any future updates to those plugins, as most of them might be ignored by plugin developers). And I can't be the only one this is happening to and has noticed this, so I figured it's possibly my MariaDB configuration instead.
